# What are secret passphrases in URL

Tags: hash, token, passphrase

I don't know much about the use of some random strings in URL.

As far as I used, I learned that it can be used where any user simply cannot guess the URL.

First noticed in phpmyadmin, as blowfish secret. and the URL said `token=secret` . I don't know about tokens.

My questions is - What are these strings anyway and are these random strings called tokens ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different uses of random strings in URLs. Your question is difficult to answer because you give us no examples, but I can describe one possible use.

A commercial site may allow users to create wish lists of products. The site may want users to be able to forward friends the URL of their wish list, but make them hard to guess. This can be implemented by adding a `WishCode` to the User record. Any time a user makes a wish list, create a string of random URL-compatible characters:

```
UserID Name       WishCode
  1076 Joe Bloggs a792f207a98d7db431bf3a56ab364e35
```

When the user adds a product to his wish list, add the product code to a Wish table:

```
UserID productID
  1076 483692
  1076 547320
  1076  73028
```

Make the Wish List page accept a WishCode URL; e.g.:

```
http://myCompanycom/wishlist/a792f207a98d7db431bf3a56ab364e35
```

When a browser submits this URL, look up the UserID from the User table, and generate a page with all the products from this user's wish list. Note that it is very difficult to guess a valid wish URL.

Also note this has nothing to do with hashing, secrets, or passphrases, nor would I call this a "token". They are unrelated concepts.